# App store connect operation error asset validation failed

Tags: xcode

Hi I got this error while uploading archive with xCode.

[image]

Does anybody had this error before ? Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. Exactly the same error. Did you found any solution?

Comment: hi there same issue here, did you found ayn solution?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: In my case increased the App version 1.0 to 1.0.1 , then clean and Archiving.

Comment: For me the problem was that an SDK version issue.  Using the Transporter app as others have suggested, I was able to see the following error: `SDK version issue. This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. All iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the problem was with the assets like it's said in the error. Don't know if it's a new requirement by apple or if it's an old one but you cannot have an alpha channel in your assets. So I just edited all my assets and deleted the alpha channels and then it worked ! Hope it help ;)

Answer (score 52):

I exported IPA from Organizer and used [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) app which finally helped me to see the issues.

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: After fixing the issue(increasing the version no) the upload happened successfully via the Transporter app.

Comment: Thank god for transporter! Actually gave me some useful error information. Process for me (might help another complete noob)...

1. Go to organiser click distribute
2. When it fails - click the download option
3. Download transporter and attempt to upload your bundle download
4. Get a useful error message and apply fix

Comment: I see that a lot of people have problems with this. Has Apple given any info on the reason why xCode app uploading is so broken?

Answer (score 41):

1. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
2. From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
3. Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.
4. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Comment: Thanks. Worth noting this still errored, but actually gave the error details allowing us to find and fix.

Comment: The year is 2022, and Apple still has no idea how to notify developers about the error! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This was a huge help! The delivery still failed in Transporter but it gave the error details. for me it was missing iPad icon files.

Comment: Xcode Cloud failed, and Xcode itself failed, but the Transporter did the job successfully. It's so weird. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

In case your current **app version is already in approved but not released** status, you cannot use the same version number. You must go higher version.

Comment: Life saver, this worked as intended

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was the version number. Once App is published on App Store, to push update use a higher version number e.g 1.0.1 (if in production we have App version 1.0.0).

Comment: same in my case also

Answer (score 8):

**Ways to fix this:**

- Check if the new version is greater than the previous version.
- In the issue navigator, you just need to apply the changes recommended by Xcode. Start clicking the issue to see the recommendations, it will prompt automatically.
- Download Transporter, to see the details of the error.

  - You need to export appName.ipa from Xcode
  - Upload the appName.ipa in the Transporter

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  Even though validation continued to fail, I eventually just tried clicking on the "Distribute App" button in Organizer.  That also failed, but gave me a much more helpful error message.  Turned out that the issue had nothing to do with Assets.  I added a redirect uri scheme that contained an invalid character.  I fixed that, and the validation succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error but when i tried to upload the app, it gives me the detailed info, i was using the same version for the latest build which apple doesn't accept. I just changed the version number for that build and able to upload the app successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the app was approved for release with the same version number. So I have to cancel the release to validate and distribute the app with the same build number. Or you can change the build number.
You can cancel the release in AppStore connect. It's a blue button on the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

i have found a solution to this problem,

you need to double check that, you have check the iphone or Ipad checkbox on xcode , but you have to upload the Iphone icons or ipad icons, one of them is missing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong in your assets. Either the app icons are not correct/missing OR you need to check your images.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I checked my assets, and indeed there was an error.

Answer (score 2):

This error message occurs by different situactions, to address your problem you can distribute your app directly to get more detail error message.

I got same message because I overrite my ios folder with a older one,
issue fixed by replacing a ios folder with a new one.( you can run "flutter create newProject" to get it)

Answer (score 2):

I am also encountering this error with an Ionic project. Even though my build failed Xcode validation, I tried to distribute it to the App Store anyway, and received the following error, which provided more detail:

> Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90713 for id 97fb5968-9248-4336-a622-e015181dd333

In Xcode I examined the app/app/assets and under AppIcon the 1024x1024px icon was missing. I added a file, generated a new build,  and subsequently was able to Archive, validate and deploy.

Answer (score 2):

The XGA-sized icon for the App Store cannot have an Alpha channel (and only that one - all other assets are OK with Alpha channels... go figure). It's one of the many, many unnecessary quirks Xcode / AppStore Connect have that drive me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

If your app has "Approved" state, but it is not released yet - you can not use same version number.

You have two options:

- increase version number (not just version code);
- cancel release (nothing will be deleted, just your approval will be cancelled), validate and distribute app, submit for approval.

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the iOS build version 3.6.3(92) to 3.6.4(92) from runner and it works fine. So, try changing your build version properly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case two mistakes, I did

```
The first one is the store version and Xcode build  versions are not matching
```

```
The second one is something wrong with our assets. (Either the app icons are not created/missing or other images)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already deployed (to the app store) the same version of the app you are attempting to validate for TestFlight, you will see this error message. The new TestFlight release must have a succeeding version number in comparison to the latest version of the app, if it is already on the app store.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a **new** project and you are uploading to the App Store for the first time, you must have app icons set in the Assets folder.

This is why it could say "Asset validation failed".

Answer (score 1):

Remove alpha channel only for the icon "**App Store iOS 1024pt**" (*Assets.xcassets*) and you will fix the issue "**App Store Connect Operation Error - Asset validation failed"**

Comment: This was my problem!  Apparently, even if there is no alpha pixels, having an alpha *channel* on your PNGs is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were some errors with the icons in `Runner/Assets`.

I just deleted those images was shown in the image bellow and everything works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too. I contacted Apple and received the following reply:

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support.
>
> We are sorry to hear that an error message is displayed in Xcode and that you are unable to distribute the app.
>
> We have checked our available resources and found that none of them correspond to the error you have inquired about.
>
> We have identified a guide that may be related to the error you are experiencing and are sending it to you below.
>
> Validate an archive of your app
>
> If you need more information, please consider visiting the Apple Developer Forums, where you can discuss development issues with Apple engineers and other developers.
>
> Developer Forums
> https://developer.apple.com/forums/
>
> For feedback on Xcode or to report a bug, please use the Feedback Assistant.
>
> Developer Feedback Assistant
> https://developer.apple.com/jp/bug-reporting/
>
> We apologize for not being able to help you with your inquiry, but we hope the above resources will be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I tried to validate my app, so I tried to distribute the app and I got a full error message, in my case was:

**Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature. The provisioning profile included in the bundle 'netoloboapps.com.mensagensProntas' (Payload/Runner.app) cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS App Store until it has a valid signature from Apple. (Expired profile signing certificate.) For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90165 for id b493faef-bcf5-4732-995d-f7c6609a0354**

My problem was a expired signing certificated. So here's the tip, check out the complete error message and see the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue, but i dont see error reporting anywhere. I build my app with Flutter and i try edit `version in pubsbec.yaml`. and i edit too `version app in xcode`. then my app success validate and distribute

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was messing some AppIcon resolution images for iPad. Also I made sure that the version and the build are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to the icons folder
/myapp/ios/App/App/Assets.xcassets/

2- Open the photo

3- Click File, then choose Export

4- Deselect from Alpha and replace the image

This should be applied to all icons

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when the WatchApp uses the healthkit api but not adds description into info.plist.

I use the Transporter App to upload, it shows the error summery.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter Developer, Change the version number. From Example in pub.yaml, 1.0.0+4 to 1.0.1+5.

Answer (score 0):

The only one solution helps me is transfer app to other AppStore account.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading the app to the app store first we need to validate the app to check whether the app has any errors or not.
Another advantage of validating app is it’ll provide detailed error.

I found 3 scenarios on which this error will occur:

=> if we are not updating the version name
=> Alpha channel in all the images of Assets.xcassets/ should be removed (you can download alpha channel remover for that)
=> if we have selected Ipad in general settings Portrait, landscape right , landscape left should be enable if we have given just portrait mode we will face the same error.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you increase the app version. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase "Current Project Version" that under Build Settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.
Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Answer (score 0):

Please check you current project app image is same as app store app icon under Included Assets